# Install Node.js with downloaded binary on Ubuntu Desktop.. Where do the files go?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu

I've downloaded Node.js directly from https://nodejs.org/en/ onto my Ubuntu Desktop operating system.  I can easily unpackage the `node-vX.X.0-linux-x64.tar.xz` file, and I can see node directories: bin, include, lib, share.  I'm guessing my download folder, `~/Downloads/node-vX.X.0-linux-x64`, is not going to be the final installation location.

My guess would be to copy all of the directory over to  `/usr/bin/node/node-vX.X.-linux-x64` but I'm not really sure.

Where do these files go?  (I've tried the readme.md file in the download and the docs on that site.  I would have thought something, somewhere on nodejs.org would have offered a bit of help...)

Is there a special installation step required here?

Comment: Why don't you just use a package manager to install nodejs on Ubuntu ?

Comment: I would suggest you use nvm because it allows you to install multiple Node.js versions in parallel and switch easily between them: https://github.com/creationix/nvm

Comment: @sand and Alexander.. those are great recommendations, but that just raises the question "Why does the site http://nodejs.org/en provide binaries for linux instead of simple instructions for a package install?"  I'm not saying no to a package install technique, I'm trying to understand why did they do it that way?

Comment: According to this link http://www.hostingadvice.com/how-to/install-nodejs-ubuntu-14-04/#standard-binary-packages you should unpack the archive in /usr/local folder

Comment: @sand, thx for the link.  I figured I can't be the first person to have this problem and I was checking the nodejs github issues list... Found [this issue](https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/418)  and one of the recommended fixes is nearly the same code as you offered up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wrote a tutorial to do exactly what you're asking: [How to get Node 6.7.0 on Linux](https://gist.github.com/rsp/edf756a05b10f25ee305cc98a161876a) - 
it's about Node 6.7.0 but you can just change the version number.

In short:

#### First get the files:

```
# If you have a 64-bit system then download binary package:
wget https://nodejs.org/dist/v6.7.0/node-v6.7.0-linux-x64.tar.gz

# If you have a 32-bit system then download a different version:
wget https://nodejs.org/dist/v6.7.0/node-v6.7.0-linux-x86.tar.gz
```

#### Extract:

```
# Extract what you downloaded:
tar xzvf node-v6.7.0-linux-x64.tar.gz

# Change the file ownership:
sudo chown -Rv root.root node-v6.7.0-linux-x64
```

#### Then install in ONE of the locations:

```
# Install files in /usr/local
sudo cp -Rvi node-v6.7.0-linux-x64/{bin,include,lib,share} /usr/local
# (change -Rvi to -Rvf if you want to overwrite existing files)

# Install files in /opt/node
sudo cp -Rvi node-v6.7.0-linux-x64 /opt/node

# Install files in /opt/node-6.7.0
sudo cp -Rvi node-v6.7.0-linux-x64 /opt/node-6.7.0
```

The difference between those 3 locations in the example is explained better in the article. The consequences are mostly related to PATH and installing multiple versions.

#### Finish the setup:

You need to make sure that directory where you have the `node` and `npm` binaries is in your PATH. See [my tutorial](https://gist.github.com/rsp/edf756a05b10f25ee305cc98a161876a) for details on how to do that.

#### Beware of shebang lines:

The shebang line of `npm` in Node installed from binaries is different than when installed from sources. This is one of the reasons I recommand building from sources if you have time for that. The other reason is that installing from sources you can do `make test` to test the version of Node on your specific system, which you cannot do when installing from binaries or with `nvm`.