# promise is not defined node js server and firebase databse

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

we have fire base database , and  server is implemented , in node js , 
we are connecting and updating ,saving data in  through node js server , to fire base database .  In in local environment (windows 7 ) , but after deploying in to compute engine ,Linux Debian server , it is giving promise is not defined  error.

error message is , Promise is not defined in firebase app.js 17 line

Comment: have any code to share?

Comment: Please show us the code in app.js

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be running an old version of Node that doesn't have native `Promise` object defined. You may need to start your program with something like:

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
```

and install `bluebird` with `npm install bluebird --save`

or to use some polyfill like:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/es6-promise-polyfill
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-polyfill

Another option would be to upgrade Node on the server. Promise object was available in Node 0.12 and you shouldn't even use that any more, not to mention anything older. For Promise support in Node see:

- http://node.green/#ES2015-built-ins-Promise

See this answers for details on how to do that:

- [node 5.5.0 already installed but node -v fetches with "v4.2.1" on OS X & homebrew?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37180505/node-5-5-0-already-installed-but-node-v-fetches-with-v4-2-1-on-os-x-homebre/37181311#37181311)
- [Install Node.js with downloaded binary on Ubuntu Desktop.. Where do the files go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42293352/install-node-js-with-downloaded-binary-on-ubuntu-desktop-where-do-the-files-go/42294905#42294905)
- [Node installed but node cannot be found in Ubuntu VPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40723668/node-installed-but-node-cannot-be-found-in-ubuntu-vps/40724019#40724019)
- [Run npm as superuser, it isn't a good idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40525238/run-npm-as-superuser-it-isnt-a-good-idea/40525676#40525676)